# Trouble defining finder method in my application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, finder

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and MySQL 5.5.37.  I want to write a finder method for my model, so I have written this (./app/models/user_object.rb):

```
class UserObject < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :day, :presence => true
  validates_numericality_of :total
  validates :object, :presence => true

  def find_total_by_user_object_and_year
    UserObject.sum(:total, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', params[:user_id], 'object = ?', params[:object], 'year(day) = ?', params[:year]])
  end

end
```

However, when I attempt to invoke the method within a controller like so

```
@my_total = UserObject.find_total_by_user_object_and_year(session["user_id"], 3, @year)
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `find_total_by_user_object_and_year' for #<Class:0x007fb7551514e0>
```

What is the right way to define my finder method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.method` to define class method:

```
def self.find_total_by_user_object_and_year
  sum(:total, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', params[:user_id], 'object = ?', params[:object], 'year(day) = ?', params[:year]])
end
```

In this case `UserObject` inside class method definition is redundant, besause it is same as `self`. Now you can write:

```
UserObject.find_total_by_user_object_and_year(params)
```